# Solving the ODE $y''+4y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The solution is $y=c_1 cox(2x)+c_2 sin(2x)$ and I am not sure how to get to get there.
I find the characteristic equation which is $$m^2+4m=0$$
I then get $$m(m+4)=0$$ so the two roots are m=0 and m=-4.
How do I do this?

Comment: The characteristic equation of $y^{(2)}+4y^{(0)}=\bf 0$ is $m^2+4=0$.

Comment: the characteristic equation you have $m^2 + 4m = 0$ correspond to $y'' + 4y' = 0.$ the correct one for $y''+4y = 0$ is $m^2 + 4 = 0.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is an ODE with constant coefficient so the 'guess' for solution is $e^{r_ix}$. For an ODE of order $n$ we must have $n$ independent solutions, since an ODE of order $n$ with constant coefficient with $e^{r_ix}$ as guess results in a polynomial equation of order $n$ thus we are done (some of these solutions may not be distinct, for example $r=2,2$ in some ODE, thus instead of writing two $e^{2x}$, our guess is now $e^{2x}$ and $xe^{2x}$).

$y=e^{rx}\implies (r^2+4)e^{rx}=0\implies (r^2+4)=0\implies r=+2i, -2i$

$y=C'_1e^{r_1x}+C'_2e^{r_2x}=c_1 cox(2x)+c_2 sin(2x)$

For more learning in a simple writing you can download for free [this](http://a.bookzz.org/book/2367972/0dd73b) beautiful book to study the first chapter, if you wish.

Comment: where did you get $e^r$ from?

Comment: @user204450 he's looking for particular solutions of that form. As the space of solutions is of dimension 2, he only need exhibit two linearly independent solutions, all other solutions will then just be linear combinations of those.

Comment: SO if it is an ODE you have the particular solution in the form $e^x$?

Comment: @Amir why do you have i next to the 2?

Comment: @user204450: $i=\sqrt{-1}$. And, $exp(ix)+exp(-ix)=2cos{x}$ and $exp(ix)-exp(-ix)=2sin{x}$

Comment: @Amir I know that but why do you need it here? Surely the square root of 4 is just -2 and + 2? Why does i come into it?

Comment: Are you serious?! $r^2+4=0\implies r^2=-4$

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry. I made a mistake when I was writing down the question and got the signs mixed up in my notes and I kept referring to my notes. Sorry. And thanks for your help

Comment: No worries. If you download the book I mentioned in the answer, you can learn a lot about some types of ODE in few pages of first chapter.

Comment: @Amir this may seem like a stupid question but what is an example of a ode with no constant coefficient?

Comment: Good question; an example of ODE with no constant coefficient:  $x^2y''+3xy'=2$. Cauchy type ODE.

Comment: How can you spot a ODE with no constant coefficient? What are the features? Thanks for your help

Comment: I am sorry but it's an extensive field and not possible to discuss it effectively if don't know an introductory to ODE; if you study any first pages of any of many books titled ODE, you can find MUCH more than you may expect; afterwards, if you have any question not understanding those materials you may ask in this website. Cheers. Sorry I couldn't help.

Comment: @AMir No worries, I understand. Thanks for your help mate :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the ansatz $y(x) = \exp(mx)$ with some constant $m$. By inserting this into ODE you get the characteristic equation $m^2 + 4 = 0$, so that $m$ is either $+2i$ or $-2i$. In other words, general solution has a form $y(x) = A \exp(2ix) + B \exp(-2ix)$, which can be equivalently written as $y(x) = C cos(2x) + D sin(2x)$ (where $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$ are constants).